# Couldn't use JSON Data in an viewController extension?

Tags: arrays, json, uitableview, swift5

could anybody please let me know what I did wrong here?
I couldn't pass the JSON data from URLSession.shared.dataTask to outer extension
Nor could bring the 
func numberOfSections .. etc to be used in the URLSession.shared.dataTask

Any help appreciated, thank you for your time.

Swift

struct getSubData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct Section: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let subData: [getSubData]
}

class indexViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = "https://nabulsi.com/nabulsi_app/main_sections_v4.json"
                         let urlObj = URL(string: url)
                         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!){(data, response, error) in
                             do {
                                 let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([Section].self, from: data!)
                                for section in sections {
                                    print(section.name)
                                    let sectionName = section.name
                                    for data in section.subData {
                                        print(data.name)
                                        let subSectionName = data.name
                                    }
                                }
                             } catch {
                                 print("We got an error")
                             }
                         }.resume()
}
```

}

extension indexViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionName.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionName[section].subSectionName?.count ?? 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = sectionName[indexPath.section].subSectionName?[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonDecoder class has no chance to parse your data just because of the received **JSON** text from the server **is not a valid format**.

Here is your endpoint, open it in the web browser: https://nabulsi.com/nabulsi_app/main_sections_v4.json

And here is the JSON validator tool: https://jsonlint.com

Copy and paste to validate your server response to the ***JSON validator tool*** called ***jsonlint***, and you will see where is your wrong.

Probably it's not your fault. It's about your backend developer if you didn't write by yourself. Contact him to fix the JSON format. After fixing the issue please notify me. I am gonna fix your parse codes if it's still not working as you expected.

- EDIT: After fixing problem, the related codes here:

[0] - Parsed json values assigned to local variable.

```
class indexViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var sections: [Section] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = "https://nabulsi.com/nabulsi_app/main_sections_v4.json"
    let urlObj = URL(string: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!){(data, response, error) in
        do {
            let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([Section].self, from: data!)
            self.sections = sections // [0]

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print("We got an error")
        }
    }.resume()
  }
}
```

- Look at the code and follow these brief explanation:

[1] - Return every rows in section, from local array

[2] - Assigned the name variable to label for current row

[3] - Assigned the name variable to header for current section

```
extension indexViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let subDatas = sections[section].subData // [1]
    return subDatas.count ?? 0
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    // [2]
    let currentSection = sections[indexPath.section]
    let currentSubdata = currentSection.subData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentSubdata.name

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3653766513, blue: 0.1507387459, alpha: 1)

    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 15, height: 40))
    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    lbl.text = sections[section].name // [3]
    lbl.textAlignment = .right
    view.addSubview(lbl)

    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
  }
}
```

Happy Coding! =]

Comment: But the: prints in the loop (for section in sections) works fine! I just need to use the returned JSON data in the tableView

Comment: okay, if you have store the returned JSON data from outside of the URLSession body, you have to notify the table view for reloading: 'new data is here'. 
Do you have a tableView outlet variable? 
for example @IBOutlet tableView: UITableView! 

If there is a tableView outlet, please add this line at the end of the for loop in do { } block in URLSession task: 
DispatchQueue.main.async { tblView.reloadData() }

Comment: if you don't have an outlet, however, if you have a chance to share your code from GitHub to me, I will fix this issue and you will better understand the solution.

Comment: sure, here is the code; note: this is the last version I reached today, still not working :( .. thank you for your help. code is in the next comment

Comment: here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4y6tkm1rprzxjg/SectionInTableView.zip?dl=0
Thank you

Comment: The problem is after JSON parse, you didn't assign to your local variable array called 'sections', and after that, you didn't use it the right way, the actual value in section and it's rows. For clear coding, maybe you can change your variable name, for example, rename the 'sections' array, to 'sectionArray'.

Comment: here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16MnRwFRDG_dZRG2_32gxFxgmtjZNnmDC

Comment: I updated the codes and upload the file to the cloud, also I edited my answer upstair. You can check it out, and if it's working as you expected, please upvote this answer and accept it. Sign it "best answer" for my motivation. =] Happy Coding!

Comment: may I add just one more thing? to fully understand how nested JSON works

Comment: What if there is root dictionary that holds all json Data, example: https://nabulsi.com/nabulsi_app/sections.json 
I used: 
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: [Sections]
}
what else do i have to change other than: 
let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: data!)

much appreciated if you could help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Just take you section Array outside your function. Keep it as property of your controller.

```
class indexViewController: UIViewController { 

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var sections: [Section] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = "https://nabulsi.com/nabulsi_app/main_sections_v4.json"
    let urlObj = URL(string: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {
     [weak self](data, response, error) in
     do {
          self?.sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([Section].self, from: data!)
          for section in sections {
            //your code goes here                         
          }
    } 
    catch {
      print("We got an error")
    }
  }.resume()
}
```